# How can I reuse return values in a Python class without rerunning the function every time?

Tags: python, function, class

I'm having a problem when reusing a function inside a class. I would like to get the return value of a function without rerunning it every time I use it. What is the best way of doing this inside a class?

Thank you!

```py
class Test():

    def __init__ (self):
        # self.my_list = my_list()

        pass


    @staticmethod
    def my_list():
        set_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
        print ('you are not refrencing')

        return set_list

    @staticmethod
    def func_test():
        func_list = Test.my_list()
        return func_list


    @staticmethod
    def func_test2():
        func_list = Test.my_list()
        return func_list

    @staticmethod
    def print_func():
        print Test.my_list()
        print Test.func_test()
        print Test.func_test2()

        return

Test.print_func()
```

here is my current result:

```
you are not referencing 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
you are not referencing
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
you are not referencing
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would get this result instead

```
you are not referencing 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: set the variable as a class attribute?

Comment: Use a [Memoize](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) decorator.

Comment: set the variable Test.my_list in the init method, that will set the variable as a class variable and then you can use by referencing Test.my_list in your static methods.  actually you don't need this to be in a class but with what you have that is a way you could go.

Answer (score 3):

If your functions are *pure* (no side effects/same inputs always produce the same outputs), you can use memoization with [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=memoizing#functools.lru_cache), which caches the output for a given set of inputs. (This is backed by a dict, so the arguments must be hashable.)

If the function is not pure (like your example with the `print()` call inside) then adding this decorator will change the behavior: the side effects will be skipped on the following calls. Also be very careful when you return a mutable value (like a list) because the same cached object will be returned, even if anything has mutated it, which might not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools

class Test():

    def __init__ (self):
        # self.my_list = my_list()

        pass


    @staticmethod
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)
    def my_list():
        set_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
        print ('you are not refrencing')

        return set_list

    @staticmethod
    def func_test():
        func_list = Test.my_list()
        return func_list


    @staticmethod
    def func_test2():
        func_list = Test.my_list()
        return func_list

    @staticmethod
    def print_func():
        print (Test.my_list())
        print (Test.func_test())
        print (Test.func_test2())

        return

Test.print_func()
```

you can try this code if you are in python 2.7

```
from repoze.lru import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=500)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: even i was unaware of it.

Comment: Hi Jainil and Gilch,

Thank you for the quick reply, Unfortunately I'm using python 2.7 and I cannot use @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False) otherwise it works perfectly

Comment: I'm trying to do what LahasaDad mentioned about setting the variable Test.my_list in the init method and reference it in other functions but I keep getting error. can someone please show me how to do this, Thank you very much for being responsive!

Comment: we don't have 2.7 installed but you can try repoze library from github.